# how to search for Unicode character using vim character class and reoder their position

Tags: regex, vim, unicode

Given

```
数据     Data
子树      subtree
```

Desired output

```
Data  数据
subtree 子树
```

For non unicode, this can be achieved using command
`s/\(\w\+\) \+\(\w\+\)/\2 \1/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following collection includes all "word characters" as matched by `\w` as well as all characters in the CJK Unified Ideographs Unicode block:

```
[0-9A-Za-z\u4E00-\u9FFF]
```

[image: search]

See `:help collection`.

It can be used as-is in place of `\w` in your pattern:

```
:%s/\([0-9A-Za-z\u4E00-\u9FFF]\+\) \+\([0-9A-Za-z\u4E00-\u9FFF]\+\)/\2 \1
```

[image: substitute]

That specific range (largely) covers the characters you provided in your sample. You may have to adjust it if your real world requirements are different.